# [Wordpress 4.6][Query] Ordering not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on an e-commerce website and we found that the best sales widget wasn't ordering as expected the products.

I tested the query's arguments and they seems right, and whatever ordering i choose, the query refuse to order the products.

Here an example :

```
$args = array(
                'post_type'             => 'product',
                'post_status'           => 'publish',
                'numberposts'           => -1,
                'meta_key'              => 'total_sales',
                'orderby'               => 'meta_value_numeric',
                'meta_type'             => 'NUMERIC'
            );

$products = get_posts( $args );

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $sales = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'total_sales');
    echo $sales[0];
}
```

Here the results :

```
144
1981
70
26
65
84
148
109
748
48
15
78
```

I checked in the database, and the value are numbers (no array or else).

After checking, they are ordered by date (DESC).

I tried the following :
- Setting orderby with meta_value_num or meta_value.
- Removing the meta and choosing orderby title.

But none of them ordered the results.

I've worked on other websites with this kind of request and never had a problem with the ordering.

Does someone have an idea where the problem could be coming from ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

in your query Try using :

'orderby'  => 'ID'

Or

you can also sort $products array using asort($products).

visit http://php.net/manual/fr/function.asort.php for more informations